# How to re-use .xib file as a template to another .xib file within one application?

Tags: iphone, xib

How to re-use .xib file as a template to another .xib file within one application.
I want one xib which will be like a template (for example xib with logo)
and I will import it like a subview on another xib file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a new view in the xib that you want to import, and create a class file:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
```

Set MyView as the class of your xib view, in the object inspector.
From the other xib, place an empty view, then change its class to `MyView`

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I did it with singleton and it works very good